# Windows Security / Share permissions

Tags: windows, privacy, permissions

I took over the role of system admin recently. Last night our servers restarted for some reason and the Users shared folder lost its setting. When users came into work their shared drive showed as offline. Once I fixed the sharing issue by sharing the folder again, this time when users open the folder they see everyone's folders. They don't have access to others folders but they can see every single folder. In my previous company the folders were named same as same as the username, here they are named with the full name of the person. I was going to write a script to map their network drivers but I can't...

My question is, how do I hide every folder from the user and have them only see their folder when they click their shared folder drive? So if the user clicks it, they only see their own folder.

Answer (score 0):

The way that this should be done is creating a \Server\Home or \Server\Home$\ share for users personal drives. then each user's personal drive should be mapped directly to a folder inside that share (\Server\Home$\CKnutson) or (\Server\Home$\User2). You can do this in a windows enviornment by mapping their drive to "\server\share\%username%" as this will resolve their account, and map to their private folder. This will not confuse any users with having to click into a folder to have proper modify access either.

You could keep it the way it is and look into "Access based enumeration", but that adds some complexity to it.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772681(v=ws.10).aspx